# Remove html before and after body tag

Tags: bash

> Script will recursively scan all html and htm pages
>   from the location specified as argument. Secondly for each file
>   removes everything before the `<body>` and everything after the
>   `</body>` including the `<body>` and `</body>`. Thirdly, result should
>   be saved in another file, if original file for example called
>   `index.html`, it becomes then `index.html_nobody`.

I wrote this code but it is not giving desired result. 
Expected result is that the script creates new file, with the new content in it. As of is now it's only creating a file named `{}_nobody` and leaves it empty.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $( ls $1 -r );
do
    if [ -d $file ];
    then
        find -type f -name "*.html" -o -name "*.htm" -exec sed -e '1,/<body/ s/.*/ /' -e '/<\/body>/,$ s/.*/ /' "{}" > "{}_nobody" \;

        echo "Success!"

        exit 0
    fi
done

echo "Unvalid path, please try again."

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First issue:** You don't need the loop or the `if` statement. `find` already recurses through a directory tree so all you have to do is call it once. Pass `"$1"` as its first argument to get it to search there.

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.html" -o -name "*.htm" \
    -exec sed -e '1,/<body/ s/.*/ /' -e '/<\/body>/,$ s/.*/ /' "{}" > "{}_nobody" \;
```

**Second issue:** The `-o` OR operator requires parentheses to make sure `-exec` applies to both branches.

```
find "$1" -type f '(' -name "*.html" -o -name "*.htm" ')' \
    -exec sed -e '1,/<body/ s/.*/ /' -e '/<\/body>/,$ s/.*/ /' "{}" > "{}_nobody" \;
```

**Third issue:** Redirections like `>` don't work with `find -exec`. The problem is that the shell sees `> "{}_nobody"` before `find` even gets a chance to run. It ends up opening a file called `{}_nobody` and redirecting all of find's output to it, rather than applying the redirection to the many `sed` invocations.

Getting it to work is a bit hairy. You have to start an explicit subshell, which is--well, take a look:

```
find "$1" -type f '(' -name "*.html" -o -name "*.htm" ')' \
    -exec bash -c 'sed -e "1,/<body/ s/.*/ /" -e "/<\/body>/,\$ s/.*/ /" "$1" > "${1}_nobody"' -- {} \;
```

To make sense of this, read it as `-exec bash -c '<script>' -- {} \;`. Following `-c '<script>'` are the script's arguments: `$0`, `$1`, `$2`, etc. We don't care what `$0` is, so convention is to pass `--`. We'll set `$1` to `{}`, which is the name of the file being processed.

Then you see that inside the script `$1` is used twice. The second time it's surrounded with curly braces to make sure bash doesn't think you have a variable named `$1_nobody`.

You could simplify this mess by putting the `sed` command in its own script. Let's say you have that script read from `$1` and write to `$2`. Then the `find` call would be the more manageable:

```
find "$1" -type f '(' -name "*.html" -o -name "*.htm" ')' \
    -exec ./stripHtml {} {}_nobody \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a *nix like OS which is likely to have Perl installed, you can run a simple one liner which will extract the value you want and will create a backup copy with "_nobody" extension:

```
$ perl -n0777 -i_nobody -e 'print $1 if /<body>(.*?)<\/body>/s' index.html
```

-n adds while loop

-0 777 causes file slurping

-i index.html is now edited and original contents are placed in index.html_nobody

print $1 - print everything matched by non-greedy regex (.*?)

/s - multiline regex match - https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch06_07.htm

**Example index.html** index.html_nobody will have the same contents

```
<html>
<body><h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p></body>
</html>
```

**index.html** after running the one liner

```
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```